# Prohibit Right Click Action On SWF files

Tags: html, flash, right-click

I have a swf file and a html page which shows the swf file. I want to prohibit right click on swf file. I do not mean removing right click menu, I just want to prohibit the right click action. Then if you right click nothing will be happened.

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#swf-holder').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


    <title>Help Me</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">html {overflow: hidden;}</style>
    <style type="text/css">body { background-color: #07090e }#swf-holder { margin-top: 0px; width: 715px; position: center; top: 0px; left: 0%; margin-left: 0px; }</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="swf-holder"><object id="content" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="715" height="580"><param name="movie" value="Main.swf" /><param name=quality value=best /><param name=bgcolor value=#07090e /><param name=allowScriptAccess value=always /><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><object id="gecko" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Main.swf" width="715" height="580" bgcolor=#4A4A4A wmode="opaque" quality="best"><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" border="0" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></object></object></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any trick or idea for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this under the HEAD of your HTML page

```
<script language="text/javascript">
var message="Function Disabled!";
function clickIE4() {
    if (event.button==2) {
        alert(message); return false;
    }
}
function clickNS4(e) {
    if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all) {
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
            alert(message); return false;
        }
    }
}
if (document.layers) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
} 
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById) {
    document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
</script>
```

(Edited code just for formatting reasons)

SOURCE: [Hypergurl](http://www.hypergurl.com/norightclick.html)

There are some other methods on that page which may help you, but this seems like the easiest to implement.

Also, just so you are aware, if visitors to your site really want to get your content, there isn't any way to stop them from getting it other than not displaying it, using the right tools in the right browser, I (and you) can get an image off a site easily.

Comment: Hi JakeJ, Thanks for your reply. But I just want t prohibit right click on my swf file. This code can disable right click from other objects. iNow If I right click on my swf file, the "settings... and About..." menu items will be shown. I want to remove entire right click menu from swf file.

Comment: @Majid Perhaps you could try putting the SWF inside an element with an ID, and use jQuery to capture all right clicks within that ID and just return false (returning false on a right click action 'SHOULD' stop the menu from opening, when I have the time I will do a code and post another answer if you think this will help

Comment: Hi JakeJ, Yes if you can provide me the code which I can only copy and paste, it would be perfect :)

Comment: Just added the code, answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144277/prohibit-right-click-action-on-swf-files/7150512#7150512)

Answer (score 1):

**Method: Prohibit right-click menu in an ID and it's children**

This small code will stop the user from right-clicking in the given ID (Can be easily changed to suit any object). Just make sure you have a set width and height of the containing ID.

To Implement:

Copy this code directly into your HEAD.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#swf-holder').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Then in your Body, find the element you want to protect (SWF Div) and add the attribute `id="swf-holder"`

Hope this works for you, took me a little reading to find it.

I made a JSFiddle for it too, link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4wNnT/)

Comment: Hi JakeJ; Thanks for your reply but did not work :(, I have edited my first post and added the html code, please review it, maybe I'm doing something wrong which I do not know it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Majid it could be the we browser that you are using. The problem is that each browser is different, and right clicking is a near impossible thing to disable as it's a system control. What are you trying to do by stopping the right click? Are you trying to disallow the user from viewing something about the file or something similar?

Comment: @Majid Oh and I put that into a JSFiddle and I cannot right click on the SWF area so I'm not sure why it's not working for you

Comment: Hi JakeJ, I have tested it on both FireFox and IE, but nothing, Did you review my html code? do you think something is wrong there?

Comment: @Majid There isn't anything obvious wrong with your code at the moment, I will take a look at it a little later on but I don't know if there is a possibility of actually removing the right click function. The only thing that I can think of as a last resort is to float a transparent `<div>` element over the SWF, so when you right click, you are actually right clicking the DIV and not the SWF, unless you need interaction then this will not work. But this is not a very nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the right click on flash SWF file make sure you include the settings shown in **BOLD** 

I just tested it correclty on **IE9**

     <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="540" height="140">
    <param name="movie" value="flashmovie.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" / >
    **<param name="menu" value="false" />**
    <embed src="flashmovie.swf"
    quality="high"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    WMODE="transparent"
    **menu="false"**
    width="540"
    height="140"
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
    allowScriptAccess="always" />
    </object>

Taken from 
http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_disablerightclick.htm